# RxJava2 flatMap create duplicate events

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm relatively new on RxJava2 and I'm getting some weird behaviors, so it's likely that I'm using the tool on the wrong way.

It's a fairly big project, but I've separated the snippet below as a minimum reproducible code:

```
Observable
  .interval(333, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Integer>>() {
    private Subject<Integer> s = PublishSubject.create();
    private int val = 0;

    @Override public ObservableSource<Integer> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
      val++;
      s.onNext(val);
      return s;
      }
    })
  .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
      Log.w("value: %s", integer);
     }
  });
```

This code simulates events from my rx-stream using an `.interval` and a `flatMap` receive those events "do some processing" and uses a `Subject` to push results down the stream.

The stream is an ongoing process which will have several several events.

This minimum code is silly because I'm pushing only on the `apply` callback, but in the real case there're several possible moments that a push can happen and the number of events being received during `apply` is not the same amount that will be sent via the Subject.

What I expected to see with this code is:

```
value: 2  // 1 got skipped because onNext is called before there's a subscriber.
value: 3
value: 4
value: 5
value: 6 ... etc
```

what I actually got is:

```
value: 2
value: 3
value: 3 // 3 twice
value: 4
value: 4
value: 4 // 4 repeated 3 times
value: 5
value: 5
value: 5
value: 5 // 5 repeated 4 times
value: 6
value: 6
value: 6
value: 6
value: 6 // 6 repeated 5 times
 ... etc
```

I've also tried to have an `Observable<Integer> o = s.share();` and returning it, or return directly `s.share();` with the same results.

I kind of understand why this is happening. The `ObservableSource` gets subscribed again n again n again so there're more events on every loop.

**The question:**

How can I achieve my expected behavior?

(in case my expected behavior was not clear, please ask more on the comments)

Comment: I would try moving `private Subject<Integer> s = PublishSubject.create();` on a different scope if I were in you

Comment: @Blackbelt as I said. That's a minimum reproducible code. On the complete code the `Function` have its own class.

Comment: I can judge what I see and I can't guess what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PublishSubject` is subscribed to *multiple times*, once per item from interval().

Edit: You will need to pass in a new `PublishSubject` each time (switch to `BehaviorSubject` if you'd like to retain the first/last emission); pass that to the long-running process, and ensure that its `onComplete` is called properly when the long-running process finishes.

Comment: That I already said. My question is how to achieve the behavior I need?

Comment: Edited answer with recommendations.

Comment: Also, I think that using PublishSubject is a bit cumbersome. consider integrating your long-running process more closely with Rx.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not gonna work. The long process in reality is running for as long as the app is open and onComplete is just ignored. What I "wanted" is to replace the given Observable with a different one that will be subscribed to the original one but notify unrelated events. Those are not 1-1 matching. Those events arrive, I have we're creating enter/update/exit (timeout) events. And those can come from different sources (different ID). I managed to do what I wanted but it's VERY VERY hacky and cumbersome, using the `to(...)` operator.

Comment: Have you considered using the `switchMap` operator? Or simply having a singleton `Subject` that is accessible all across your app?

Comment: Thanks. `switchMap` pointed me on the right direction. Check my answer for the complete solution I used.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

After recent comments I could come up with this kind of a solution:

```
class MyBluetoothClient {
  private PublishSubject<BTLEEvent> statusPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create()

  public Observable<BTLEEvent> getEventObservable() {
    return statusPublishSubject
  }

  private void publishEvent(BTLEEvent event) {
    statusPublishSubject.onNext(event)
  }

  public void doStuff1() {
    // do something that returns:
    publishEvent(BTLEEvent.someEvent1)
  }

  public void doStuff2() {
    // do something else that eventually yields
    publishEvent(BTLEEvent.someEvent2)
  }
}
```

And you use it in this way:

```
MyBluetoothClient client = MyBluetoothClient()
client
  .getEventObservable()
  .subscribe( /* */ )

///

client.doStuff1()

/// 

client.doStuff2
```

**Original answer**

Will this do?

```
Observable
  .interval(333, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Integer>>() {
    private int val = 0;

    @Override public ObservableSource<Integer> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
      val++;
      return Observable.just(val);
      }
    })
  .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
    @Override public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
      Log.w("value: %s", integer);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For this very small example code I wrote it would. But if you read the complete question, the Subject can fire new events at anytime based on other conditions. My first thing in the morning back in the office I'll try Tassos suggestion of using a switchMap instead

Comment: I see. It's hard for me to come up with a better answer given as little as you do. Just note that you can return any kind of an Observable, like Observable.range(0, 5).map(...).take(4) ... and so on. Give me something more and I'll try to come up with a better answer ;)

Comment: A more concrete use cases I have (from several others): Listening to bluetooth LE scans, parse the advertisement frame (map), filter expected frames, and (on this issue) separate the readings into "enter" event, "update rssi" event and use a timeout to generate an "exit" event. So the class is keeping timestamp of each event as they arrive in a Map and running every second a check to timeout "exit" devices.

Comment: That means this `Observable` will generate 3 even types (enum enter, update, exit) from any number of possible BLE devices from any possible of scan events. Tomorrow 1st thing in the office I'll give a try with `.switchMap` instead.

Comment: I updated the answe, hope this is closer to the truth

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I can't see how I could use this inside the the Observable fluent API.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the answer I came up with. I'll mark @Tassos answer as correct as he pointed me out on the right path.

First I need a `CachedSubject` (a subject that caches items while there's no observers and dispatches them as soon as an observer connects), this is necessary to make sure emissions from inside the `apply` really gets through. The class mostly wraps a `PublishSubject`.

```
class CachedSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {

        private PublishSubject<T> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        private Queue<T> cache = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

        @Override public boolean hasObservers() {
            return publishSubject.hasObservers();
        }

        @Override public boolean hasThrowable() {
            return publishSubject.hasThrowable();
        }

        @Override public boolean hasComplete() {
            return publishSubject.hasComplete();
        }

        @Override public Throwable getThrowable() {
            return publishSubject.getThrowable();
        }

        @Override protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer) {
            while (cache.size() > 0) {
                observer.onNext(cache.remove());
            }
            publishSubject.subscribeActual(observer);
        }

        @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            publishSubject.onSubscribe(d);
        }

        @Override public void onNext(T t) {
            if (hasObservers()) {
                publishSubject.onNext(t);
            } else {
                cache.add(t);
            }
        }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
            publishSubject.onError(e);
        }

        @Override public void onComplete() {
            publishSubject.onComplete();
        }
    }
```

then I use this class with a `switchMap`:

```
Observable
   .interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
   .switchMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Integer>>() {

      private Subject<Integer> s = new CachedSubject<>();
      private int val = 0;

      @Override public ObservableSource<Integer> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception {
         val++;
         s.onNext(val);
         return s;
      }
   })
   .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
      @Override public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
         Log.w("value: %s", integer);
      }
   });
```

This effectively allows me to receive any number of events on the `apply<T t>` method and have only 1 `Consumer` subscribed to it, receiving all the events from it.